# Why does logging out user from firebase require error handling, but not getting current user?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm a bit new to error handling in swift. After going through multiple firebase tutorials I've become accustomed to mindlessly writing out my error handlers without understanding why they are required for certain cases and not required for others. I know that any time an error can be thrown, I must handle the error but I don't always know why an error might be thrown in the first place.

Why do we not need an error handler when getting the current user?

```
guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else {return}
```

But we do need one for signing out a user?

```
func logout() {
    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {
        // there is a user signed in 
        do {
            try? FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
        } catch {
            print("failed to sign out user")
    }
}
```

Don't both have the potential to throw errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing out is really just a matter of forgetting whatever tokens were previously in place that identified the user.  Nothing else really needs to happen that could "fail" and prevent the signout from finishing.